# Node & Sequelize: How to share database schema between developers?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In Node.js, what is the best way to share a database schema between developers without running each and every migration? Right now I'm using `Sequelize` as an ORM.

For example, in Rails, there is a `schema.rb` file that can be run to get any empty database installation up to speed with the current schema.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on `sequelize.sync()` after you have defined your model in javascript. You would have to ensure you include every migration in the definitions of the model, so that simply calling `sync()` should bring the database up to date.